# Send json coordinates with ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, json, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I am trying to send my JSON data to PHP and decode it but i am getting the error each time i send it can someone help me help Thanks.

this is my JavaScript code:

```
 var calcButton = document.getElementById('anim');
        calcButton.onclick = function() {
            var data = draw.getAll();

            var polyCoord = turf.meta.coordAll(data);
            console.log(polyCoord);

            var jsondata = JSON.stringify({coordonnés: polyCoord});
            console.log(jsondata); 

            /*const jsonEnvoie = JSON.parse(jsondata);
            console.log(jsonEnvoie.coordonnés[0]); */

             $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost/drone/model.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: {'ajaxdata': JSON.stringify(jsondata)},

                        success: function (data, status) {
                            console.log("success updating status.");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            console.log("error updating status.");
                        }
                    });

        };
```

this my PHP code:

```
$myArray = json_decode($_POST['ajaxdata']);

var_dump($myArray);
```

Comment: Aaaaaand what is the error?

Comment: Also - why are you using JSON.stringify multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> contentType: 'application/json',
> ```

You are claiming you are sending a JSON encoded request.

There are two problems with this:

1. PHP doesn't know how to decode that kind of request into `$_POST`
2. You are sending URL encoded data, not JSON encoded data (although one of the values in the URL encoded data is JSON)

Remove the lying `contentType` line.